# Weird $_POST PHP issue

Tags: php

Congrats to me. I've officially make the switch from asp.net to PHP.

Now, I'm stuck. :-)

I have some code that I found on some code snippets site and have a question about the following piece.

```
if (isset($_POST['doRegCheck']))
    : if (intval($_POST['doRegCheck']) == 0 || empty($_POST['doRegCheck']))
    : redirect_to("index.php?do=users");
 endif;

endif;
```

Can anyone tell me exactly what is going here? Does this code check the value of the doRegCheck POST variable to make sure it's not empty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code will redirect only if the HTTP headers contain a variable called `doRegCheck` and that variable is set to 0 (`?doRegCheck=0`), or nothing (`?doRegCheck=`). That seems backwards to me. I would think you would redirect if the variable is present and it's not set to falsy values like `0,false,F`

That syntax (colons) is usually used in templates (when you're switching in and out of PHP mode), makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's reformat this properly:

```
if (isset($_POST['doRegCheck'])) :
    if (intval($_POST['doRegCheck']) == 0 || empty($_POST['doRegCheck'])) :
        redirect_to("index.php?do=users");
    endif;
endif;
```

Then, let's take out the redundancies. `empty` basically includes a check for `isset`. `empty` will also recognize `"0"` as "empty". `empty` recognizes any *false* value or non-existent value as "empty". This code *may* try to check of the value is numeric by using `intval`. So to summarize, this should be more comprehensible:

```
if (empty($_POST['doRegCheck']) || !is_numeric($_POST['doRegCheck'])) {
    redirect_to("index.php?do=users");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the right idea, if 'doRegCheck' is set, but equal to '0' or has no value '' then it will redirect you to 'index.php?do=users'.  So as far as I can tell it's basically making sure that if you hit say a registration page without a confirmation it will not complete the registration process.

Answer (score 0):

The current form makes the readability harder as it is, it should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['doRegCheck'])):
     if (intval($_POST['doRegCheck']) == 0 || empty($_POST['doRegCheck'])):
     redirect_to("index.php?do=users");
     endif;
endif;
```

Which translates to:

```
if (isset($_POST['doRegCheck'])){
     if (intval($_POST['doRegCheck']) == 0 || empty($_POST['doRegCheck'])){
     redirect_to("index.php?do=users");
     }
}
```

Meaning:

```
//is $_POST['doRegCheck'] set
if (isset($_POST['doRegCheck'])){
     //intval will return (int)0 even if its abc,
     // perhaps it should be is_numeric() as it will
     // pass if the value is 0 or the value is abc or empty
     if (intval($_POST['doRegCheck']) == 0 || empty($_POST['doRegCheck'])){
     //some user function to redirect
     redirect_to("index.php?do=users");
     }
}
```